# UIButton image won't change when I click on it

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, uibutton

I have `button` in my `TableViewCell` class with a default image of a box. I want the image of the `button` to change to another image when it is selected, however this is not working for me.

This is the `TableViewCell` class:

```
class NameHeaderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkButton: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setup(model: UserModel) {
        nameLabel.text = model.name
    }
}
```

In my `ViewController`, I added a target to change the state of the `button` when it is clicked:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let userModel = Data.userModels[section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "nameCell") as! NameHeaderTableViewCell

    cell.setup(model: userModel)
    cell.checkMarkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)



    cell.enable(on: false)
    if isUserEditing == true {
        cell.enable(on: true)
    }
    return cell.contentView
}
@objc func handleTap(sender: UIButton) {
    
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

//This just enables and disables the table headers depending on if there is text in a UITextField
extension UITableViewCell {
    func enable(on: Bool) {
        for view in contentView.subviews {
            view.isUserInteractionEnabled = on
            view.alpha = on ? 1 : 0.5
        }
    }
}
```

I also set the images for the certain states in the `storyboard`:

[image: For the default state, I set the image to an unchecked box]
[image: For the selected state, I set the image to a checked box]

Again, when there is text in the `textfield`, the cells become enabled, however when I try to click on the `button`, the image does not change. I've double checked and even made sure the Target Membership was correct with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: My guess would be that it has something to do with you `isSelected` toggle for the button. You should take a look if the value is not already changed before doing `if sender.isSelected { sender.isSelected = false } ...`. If there is some default method that changes this value, your `if { } else { }` would change it again, maintaining it in the same state

Comment: I've looked at my code and can't find anything that would affect the state of my button. Not sure if this is helpful but when I add this: `if sender.isSelected {
   sender.isSelected = false
   print(false)
  } else {
   sender.isSelected = true
   print(true)
  }`
The console always prints true

Comment: I think tableView.reloadData() in handleTap is the problem. You are reloading the entire table which leads to reload of the section header as well (viewForHeaderInSection being called again) and hence the button resets itself. Either you need to manually insert/delete the rows or persist the state of the button so that on reload, you can use it.

Comment: This solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this method to set the button's image programatically. Set two different images for the states `normal` and `selected`.

```
checkMarkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected_image"), for: .selected)
checkMarkButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "normal_image"), for: .normal)
```

Then in your `selector`:

```
@objc func handleTap(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I get a warning saying "Result of != is unused" even when I set the images programmatically.

Comment: Make sure you set `sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected`, **not** `sender.isSelected != sender.isSelected`. The latter evaluates to a boolean. The former changes the member `isSelected`.

Comment: This works as well, I guess I read too fast. Thanks, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested many answers but only yours helped me to solve problem with image changing.

Comment: Happy to help - and glad to hear it's still working in 2021.